# Steepest descent for the quadratic norm?

Tags: proof-explanation, convex-optimization, normed-spaces

From [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook) by Boyd & Vandenberghe:

> Let $\Delta x_{\text{snd}} = \arg \min \left\{ \nabla f(x)^T v : \|v\| = 1 \right\}$ be the normalized steepest descent direction with respect to the norm $\|*\|$. 
>  Consider the norm $ \|z\|_P = (z^T P z)^{1/2} = \| P^{1/2} z \|_2$ where $P \in S^n_{++}$ the set of positive semidefinite matrices. 
>  Then $\Delta x_{\text{snd}} = -(\nabla f(x)^T P^{-1} \nabla f(x))^{-1/2}P^{-1} \nabla f(x)$.

---

Can someone explain how  $\Delta x_{\text{snd}} =-(\nabla f(x)^TP^{-1}\nabla f(x))^{-1/2}P^{-1} \nabla f(x)$?

I see that $\Delta x_{\text{snd}} = \arg \min\{\nabla f(x)^Tv : \|v\|_P = (v^TPv)^{1/2} = \|P^{1/2}v\|_2 = 1\}$

But from here I'm not seeing how the above equality is derived.

Comment: Note that you need $P>0$ for $\|\cdot\|_P$ to be a norm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, the solution to $\min_{\|x\|=1} g^T x$ is $x = -{1 \over \|g\|} g$.
This follows from Cauchy Schwartz.

The above problem can be written as 
$\min_{\|x\|_P = 1} g^T x = \min_{\|\sqrt{P}x\| = 1} g^T x = \min_{\|y\| = 1} g^T \sqrt{P}^{-1} y $ (where the transformation $y=\sqrt{P} x$ was used).

So the solution (of the last problem) is
$y=-{1 \over \|\sqrt{P}^{-1} g\|} \sqrt{P}^{-1} g$ and converting back into the 'x' representation we have
$x = \sqrt{P}^{-1}y = -{1 \over \|\sqrt{P}^{-1} g\|} P^{-1} g $.

Note that $\|\sqrt{P}^{-1} g\| = \sqrt{g^TP^{-1} g}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \Delta x_{\textrm{nsd}} = \textrm{argmin} \{ \nabla f(x)^Tv \mid \space\space\space \vert\vert v \vert\vert_{P} \le 1 \} $$

$$ = \textrm{argmin} \{ \nabla f(x)^Tv \mid \space\space\space\vert\vert P^{1/2}v \vert\vert_{2} \le 1 \} $$

$$ = \textrm{argmin} \{ \nabla f(x)^T P^{-1/2}P^{1/2}v \mid \space\space\space \vert\vert P^{1/2}v \vert\vert_{2} \le 1 \} $$

$$ = \textrm{argmin} \{ (\nabla f(x)^T P^{-1/2})y \mid \space\space\space \vert\vert y \vert\vert_{2} \le 1 \} $$

where we set $y = P^{1/2}v$.

Now we're back in the familiar Euclidean case and so immediately conclude that the $y$ which minimizes this inner product is the unit vector pointing in the opposite direction to $\nabla f(x)^T P^{-1/2}$:

$$y^{*} = \frac{-P^{-1/2}\nabla f(x)}{\vert\vert P^{-1/2}\nabla f(x) \vert\vert_{2}} $$

$$
\implies v^{*} = \frac{-P^{-1/2}P^{-1/2}\nabla f(x)}{\vert\vert P^{-1/2}\nabla f(x) \vert\vert_{2}} $$

$$ = \frac{-P^{-1}\nabla f(x)}{\vert\vert P^{-1/2}\nabla f(x) \vert\vert_{2}} $$

$$ = \frac{-P^{-1}\nabla f(x)^{T}}{(\nabla f(x)^{T} P^{-1} \nabla f(x))^{1/2}} $$

And we're done.  To get $v^{*}$ we used $y = P^{1/2}v$ so $v = P^{-1/2}y$.

That $(\nabla f(x)^{T} P^{-1} \nabla f(x))^{1/2} = \vert\vert P^{-1/2}\nabla f(x) \vert\vert_{2}$ is given in the textbook referenced in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**My attempt**: Perhaps you can finish it
$\nabla_z ||P^{1/2}z||_2 = \frac{P^{T/2}P^{1/2} z}{||P^{1/2}z||_2}$. Now you want optimize 
$$ \min \frac{z^T P^{T/2}P^{1/2}}{||P^{1/2}z||_2} v \quad \text{s.t.}  ||v||^2_2 = 1,
$$ 
which is equivalent to
$$ \min \frac{z^T P}{||P^{1/2}z||_2} v \quad \text{s.t.}  ||v||^2_2 = 1
$$
To minimize the expression  $v$ should be in the null-space $ P $.